# Casting images to different class PIL

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, imagefilter

I'm working with PIL and trying to use the median filter on an image in order to de-noise it. But when I try, the result is a black image. What I think is the cause of the problem is the fact that the image is of class 'PIL.Image.Image'.

Let me explain what I am doing/the issue in more depth. I had to perform some image manipulations using numpy. In order to do that I first had to cast the PIL image to a numpyArray. I did this with the following code:

```
img = np.array(image)
```

After performing the needed transformations I cast the image back to PIL with the following code:

```
def numpy_to_pil(image):
    minv = np.amin(image)
    maxv = np.amax(image)
    img = Image.fromarray((255 * (image - minv) / (maxv - minv)).astype(np.uint8))
    return img
```

When I try to filter 'img' with a median filter, as previously stated, the result is a black image. This is how I use the filter function of PIL:

```
img.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter(3))
```

I tried comparing the results with an image (let's call it 'cat' (literally image of a cat)) that wasn't put through the casting process that 'img' was put through. I tried printing out the types to see what differed. This is the result:

```
cat =  <class 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'>
img =  <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
```

Seeing this I wonder if the problem is that 'img' is of type 'PIL.Image.Image' instead of 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'. Did I do something wrong whilte casting form numpyArray to PIL? Or is it something else.

Any help is greatly appreciated! (I tried being as specific as possible)

P.S: The type of noise is salt&pepper
P.P.S: I tried using `img.convert('PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile')` but it outputs the following error:

> conversion from RGB to PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile not supported

Comment: I didn't understand why my answer worked, so I narrowed down the issue and asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50897906/chaining-operations-with-uint8-vs-int64/). I've edited my question to put in why the issue occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot going on in this step: `(255 * (image - minv) / (maxv - minv)).astype(np.uint8)`.

The image is of datatype uint8 so when you multiply by 255 first, you are exceeding the maximum value of an 8-bit integer. You can either change the datatype to `int64` or break the steps out and the datatype will be cast for you earlier.

If you break those steps out and multiply by 255 last, it no longer gives a black screen because of overflowing the 8-bit integer:

```
minv = np.amin(image)
maxv = np.amax(image)
image = image - minv
image = image / (maxv - minv)
image = image * 255
img = Image.fromarray(image.astype(np.uint8))
```