# Single image evaluation for pytorch resnet model on opencv frame and png file

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, python-imaging-library

I have a video in `.mp4` format: `eval.mp4`. I also have a fine-tuned `pytorch` resnet `nn` with which I would like to perform inference on single frames that are read from the video or single png files that are saved to disk

My pre-trained `nn` successfully uses `.png` files that I load from disk and then perform the training/validation transforms. But during inference, rather than writing each frame of the `eval.mp4` video to disk as `.png` files solely for the purpose of inferring on every frame, I would like to simply transform each captured frame into the correct format that can be evaluated by the network.

My dataset classes / dataloaders look like:

```
# create total dataset, no transforms
class MouseDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):
        """
        Args:
            csv_file (string): Path to the csv file with annotations.
            root_dir (string): Directory with all the images.
            transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to be applied
                on a sample.
        """
        self.mouse_frame = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.mouse_frame)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()

        # img_name is root_dir+file_name
        img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir,
                                self.mouse_frame.iloc[idx, 0])
        image = Image.open(img_name)
        coordinates = self.mouse_frame.iloc[idx, 1:]
        coordinates = np.array([coordinates])

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        
        return (image, coordinates)

# break total dataset into subsets for different transforms
class DatasetSubset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataset, transform=None):
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.transform = transform
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataset)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        
        # get image
        image = self.dataset[index][0]
        # transform for input into nn
        if self.transform:
            image = image.convert('RGB')
            image = self.transform(image)
            image = image.to(torch.float)
            #image = torch.unsqueeze(image, 0)
        
        # get coordinates
        coordinates = self.dataset[index][1]
        # transform for input into nn
        coordinates = coordinates.astype('float').reshape(-1, 2)
        coordinates = torch.from_numpy(coordinates)
        coordinates = coordinates.to(torch.float)

        return (image, coordinates)

# create training / val split
train_split = 0.8
train_count = int(train_split * len(total_dataset))
val_count = int(len(total_dataset) - train_count)
train_subset, val_subset = torch.utils.data.random_split(total_dataset, [train_count, val_count])

# create training / val datasets
train_dataset = DatasetSubset(train_subset, transform = data_transforms['train'])
val_dataset = DatasetSubset(val_subset, transform = data_transforms['val'])

# create train / val dataloaders
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=num_workers, shuffle=True)
val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=num_workers)
dataloaders_dict = {}
dataloaders_dict['train'] = train_dataloader
dataloaders_dict['val'] = val_dataloader
```

My training vs. validation transforms (which are identical for testing purposes):

```
# Data augmentation and normalization for training
# Just normalization for validation
# required dimensions of input image
input_image_width = 224
input_image_height = 224

# mean and std of RGB pixel intensities
# ImageNet mean [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
# ImageNet standard deviation [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
model_mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
model_std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((input_image_height, input_image_width)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(model_mean, model_std)
    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((input_image_height, input_image_width)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(model_mean, model_std)
    ]),
}
```

What I've tried to do is read each frame from an `opencv` `vidcapture` object, convert to `PIL` using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232813/convert-opencv-image-format-to-pil-image-format), and then infer but the result I'm getting is very different from the simply reading the frame, saving as a `.png` and then inferring on the `.png`.

The code that I am testing:

```
# Standard imports
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import models, transforms
from PIL import Image

# load best model for evaluation
BEST_PATH = 'resnet152_best.pt'
model_ft = torch.load(BEST_PATH)
#print(model_ft)
model_ft.eval()

# Data augmentation and normalization for training
# Just normalization for validation
# required dimensions of input image
input_image_width = 224
input_image_height = 224

# mean and std of RGB pixel intensities
# ImageNet mean [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
# ImageNet standard deviation [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
model_mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
model_std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((input_image_height, input_image_width)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(model_mean, model_std)
    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((input_image_height, input_image_width)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(model_mean, model_std)
    ]),
}

# Read image
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('eval.mp4')
total_frames = cap.get(7)
cap.set(1, 6840)
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imwrite('eval_6840.png', frame)
png_file = 'eval_6840.png'

# eval png
png_image = Image.open(png_file)
png_image = png_image.convert('RGB')
png_image = data_transforms['val'](png_image)
png_image = png_image.to(torch.float)
png_image = torch.unsqueeze(png_image, 0)
print(png_image.shape)
output = model_ft(png_image)
print(output)

# eval frame
vid_image = Image.fromarray(frame)
vid_image = vid_image.convert('RGB')
vid_image = data_transforms['val'](vid_image)
vid_image = vid_image.to(torch.float)
vid_image = torch.unsqueeze(vid_image, 0)
print(vid_image.shape)
output = model_ft(vid_image)
print(output)
```

This returns:

```
torch.Size([1, 3, 224, 224])
tensor([[ 0.0229, -0.0990]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
torch.Size([1, 3, 224, 224])
tensor([[ 0.0797, -0.2219]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
```

My questions are:

(1) Why is the opencv frame evaluation different from the png file evaluation? All of the transformations appear to be identical (including the RGB conversion per the comments).

(2) How can I make the frame evaluation identical to the png evaluation given that both images are captured from the exact same segment of the video?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice fan fact about [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv): it works in BGR space, rather than RGB.

This might be the reason why you have different results processing png images (read via `PIL.Image`) vs processing video frames (read via [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv)).

Comment: Yes, thanks. That's why I have the lines `png_image = png_image.convert('RGB')` and `vid_image = vid_image.convert('RGB')` in both examples.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer here in case in helps anyone.

The issue is that: `png_image = Image.open(png_file)` creates an object of this type: `PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile`.

A vidcapture frame, however, creates an object of type: `numpy.ndarray`. And the conversion step: `vid_image = Image.fromarray(frame)` creates an object of type: `PIL.Image.Image`

I tried converting `PIL.Image.Image` object to a `PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile` and vice versa to make them comparable, but it does not seem possible using the `PIL` method `convert`. [Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880843/casting-images-to-different-class-pil) seem to have had this issue as well.

So the solution was to convert back and forth between `numpy.ndarray` types and `PIL` image types to make use of the transforms functionality in the `PIL` image library on which `pytorch` relies. Probably not the most efficient method, but end result is identical input objects and model predictions.

For reference:

```
# Read image
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('eval.mp4')
total_frames = cap.get(7)
cap.set(1, 6840)
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imwrite('eval_6840.png', frame)
png_file = 'eval_6840.png'

# eval png
png_image = Image.open(png_file)
png_array = np.array(png_image)
png_image = Image.fromarray(png_array)
png_image = data_transforms['val'](png_image)
png_image = png_image.to(torch.float)
png_image = torch.unsqueeze(png_image, 0)
png_image = png_image.to(device)
output = model_ft(png_image)
print(output)

# eval frame
vid_array = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
vid_image = Image.fromarray(vid_array)
vid_image = data_transforms['val'](vid_image)
vid_image = vid_image.to(torch.float)
vid_image = torch.unsqueeze(vid_image, 0)
vid_image = vid_image.to(device)
output = model_ft(vid_image)
print(output)
```

Yields:

```
tensor([[ 0.0229, -0.0990]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
tensor([[ 0.0229, -0.0990]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
```